# From Visual Studio in "design view", is possible to have the correspondig lines of code highlighted in "source view"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, highlighting, design-view

I use VS2010 with GridView, FormView ecc...

I frequently switch from Design View (in which for example I am visually editing something inside a FormView EditItemTemplate), to Source View.

So, for example if in Design View I have a TextBox selected, when I switch to Source View I'd like to have ONLY the corresponding  lines selected, instead VS2010 highligh ALL the FormView EditItemtemplate code, from start to finish (which can be 1000 lines long!).

Is possible to instruct VS to select only the relevant lines?

**EDIT**
Note that this happen when I am editing something inside a **EditItemTemplate**

Answer (score 0):

you can view the lines of code and the design of the page when you click the split view option in the lower left. Then if you click on the item that you want to see the code for it should move you to that section and highlight it for you.

Comment: that, of course, 'should' be the correct behaviour, but in my case that doesn't apply, maybe because the edited code in inside an **EditItemTemplate**?